# Pycharm seemingly not running code properly (?)

Tags: python, pycharm

I was changing my setting in Pycharm and ended up something that I did not want to do and, because I did not know how to put Pycharm back the way I wanted it to, I reset the setting to the original ones that come with Pycharm.

Doing this caused some issues and now I can't click on the `Run 'file'` option or the `Debug 'file'` option. These used to be green buttons but now they don't seem to be working for some reason.

**This is a picture of what it looks like**
[image: This is a picture of what it looks like]

Also, I don't know much about Pycharm but I got the error `No python interpreter configured for the project` and it might have something to do with this but I really don't know. I looked at a youtube video that told me how to fix this problem, which I did. But I can't find a solution to this one about the notebook not running.

If anyone knew the solution to this problem it would be greatly appreciated

**Run configurations**
[image: Run configurations]

Comment: Try to first run it using the green arrow at the top-right corner... Then the option should be active

Comment: That `Tests (1)` looks odd. I probably have the run configurations messed up. Can you add a screenshot of the run configurations? (press the little arrow next to `Tests (1)` in the top right corner and then Edit configurations)

Comment: Lastly, it seems like Pycharm is still indexing the interpreter (judging by the "indexing..." at the top-right and the progress bar at the bottom). Wait until it finished indexing and try again

Comment: @Tomerikoo I managed to make pycharm run but I don't know why that 1 is in Tests (1) since I only have one file called tests. I added the configurations to a link in the bottom of the post

Comment: @Tomerikoo just clicking the green arrow at the top-right corner made the option become active but check the other comment for the "Tests (1)" thing

Comment: Yep, as I thought you just have two configurations for the same file. You can just delete this one and use `Tests` instead

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you so much, but how would I do that? I notice that I can't right click on one of those options and when I edit the configurations I can't find a button that would delete it

Comment: It's that minus sign (`-`) above the configurations. There's also a `+` next to it to add new ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like reverting to default settings removed your interpreter Configuration and you have to re-enter those. Try clicking on the dropdown that says *Tests (1)* in the top right of your window and create a new run configuration for your Project (i haven't used PyCharm in a bit, but it should say something like *Edit Run Configuration*). Set the interpreter to the Python Version you want to use (or the venv if there is one configured for your Project) and select the entry Point again (in your case probably `Tests.py`).